# .htaccess redirection confliction between two pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

following is my directory structure.

```
|--inc (folder)
   |-->header.php
   |-->footer.php
|--css (folder)
|--js (folder)
|--images (folder)
|--index.php
|--product.php
|--items.php
```

the php files `index.php`, `product.php` ,`items.php` all use to include the files in `inc` folder

Now i use .htaccess to redirect my use like i want some files to redirect to `product.php` ans some files to `item.php`.

**First approach**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ./product.php?fd=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
   RewriteRule deal/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ ./item.php?id=$1&id2=$2 [L,NC,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

*In this approach the the url of contents (CSS,JS,Images,.php files) also redirects and changes to /deal/css or /deal/images etc in my `item.php` file but there is not folder name `deal`.i just added `deal` to remove confliction between two redirection*

**Second approach**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # first try to see if belongs to item.php based on URI pattern
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ ./item.php?idd=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

    # No try /j/display.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ ./product.php?fd=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

*This code also had same problem*

plz help!!! any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that you're rules are rewriting requests for your css or images or javascript, it's because you're using relative links in your content and the `/deal/` part of the URL makes the browser think you *actually want your scripts/images/css to be in the `/deal/` folder. You need to make your links absolute URLs or add a relative URI base to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question but can u please elaborate this? I am new to all this stuff.

Comment: and also i can't give absolute path because of following warnings

**Warning**: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\item.php on line 2

Warning: include(http://localhost/shop/admin/qconnect.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\item.php on line 2

**Warning:** include(): Failed opening 'http://localhost/shop/admin/qconnect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\item.php on line 2

Comment: @Anonymous When you go to a URL like: `/deal/abcd1234`, and you have a URI like this in the page's content: `<img src="images/1.png">`. The browser has to "guess" what the URL base is, and it does that by looking at the URL in the location bar (the browser is completely clueless about rewrites on the server or where the content actually resides) and it sees `/deal/`, so it uses that as the URL base, and appends that to **all relative URLs** in the content, making it look like: `/deal/images/1.pmg`